# Performing an "online" linear interpolation

Tags: time-series, matlab, interpolation

I have a problem where I need to do a linear interpolation on some data *as it is acquired* from a sensor (it's technically position data, but the nature of the data doesn't really matter). I'm doing this now in matlab, but since I will eventually migrate this code to other languages, I want to keep the code as simple as possible and not use any complicated matlab-specific/built-in functions.

My implementation initially seems OK, but when checking my work against matlab's built-in interp1 function, it seems my implementation isn't perfect, and I have no idea why. Below is the code I'm using on a dataset already fully collected, but as I loop through the data, I act as if I only have the current sample and the previous sample, which mirrors the problem I will eventually face.

```
%make some dummy data
np = 109; %number of data points for x and y
x_data = linspace(3,98,np) + (normrnd(0.4,0.2,[1,np]));
y_data = normrnd(2.5, 1.5, [1,np]);

 %define the query points the data will be interpolated over
qp = [1:100];

kk=2; %indexes through the data
cc = 1; %indexes through the query points

qpi = qp(cc); %qpi is the current query point in the loop
y_interp = qp*nan; %this will hold our solution

while kk<=length(x_data)
    kk = kk+1; %update the data counter

    %perform online interpolation
    if cc<length(qp)-1
        if qpi>=y_data(kk-1) %the query point, of course, has to be in-between the current value and the next value of x_data
            y_interp(cc) = myInterp(x_data(kk-1), x_data(kk), y_data(kk-1), y_data(kk), qpi);
        end

        if qpi>x_data(kk), %if the current query point is already larger than the current sample, update the sample
            kk = kk+1;
        else %otherwise, update the query point to ensure its in between the samples for the next iteration
            cc = cc + 1;
            qpi = qp(cc);

            %It is possible that if the change in x_data is greater than the resolution of the query
            %points, an update like the above wont work. In this case, we must lag the data
            if qpi<x_data(kk),
                kk=kk-1;
            end
        end
    end
end

%get the correct interpolation
y_interp_correct = interp1(x_data, y_data, qp);

%plot both solutions to show the difference
figure;
plot(y_interp,'displayname','manual-solution'); hold on;
plot(y_interp_correct,'k--','displayname','matlab solution');
leg1 = legend('show');
set(leg1,'Location','Best');
ylabel('interpolated points');
xlabel('query points');
```

Note that the "myInterp" function is as follows:

```
function yi = myInterp(x1, x2, y1, y2, qp)
%linearly interpolate the function value y(x) over the query point qp
yi = y1 + (qp-x1) * ( (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) );
end
```

And here is the plot showing that my implementation isn't correct :-(

[image]

Can anyone help me find where the mistake is? And why? I suspect it has something to do with ensuring that the query point is in-between the previous and current x-samples, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Please include example data for `x_data`, `y_data` and `qp`.

Comment: Sorry, are you asking me to upload the data, or just plot it?

Comment: Provide example data **in your script**, not as a separate file. You could even do `x_data=1:10; y_data=randn(1,10);` or something similar. Just make it easy for us to reproduce your issue. See [mre].

Comment: Got it -- I added a quick simulation for x_data and y_data to make the issue reproducible. Note that x_data and qp (also defined in the code to be qp = [1:100]) are indeed monotonically increasing, which is what I think is what you were asking before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you at times call `myInterp` with a value of `qpi` that is outside of the bounds `x_data(kk-1)` and `x_data(kk)`. This leads to invalid extrapolation results.

Your logic of looping over `kk` rather than `cc` is very confusing to me. I would write a simple `for` loop over `cc`, which are the points at which you want to interpolate. For each of these points, advance `kk`, if necessary, such that `qp(cc)` is in between `x_data(kk)` and `x_data(kk+1)` (you can use `kk-1` and `kk` instead if you prefer, just initialize `kk=2` to ensure that `kk-1` exists, I just find starting at `kk=1` more intuitive).

To simplify the logic here, I'm limiting the values in `qp` to be inside the limits of `x_data`, so that we don't need to test to ensure that `x_data(kk+1)` exists, nor that `x_data(1)<pq(cc)`. You can add those tests in if you wish.

Here's my code:

```matlab
qp = [ceil(x_data(1)+0.1):floor(x_data(end)-0.1)];
y_interp = qp*nan; % this will hold our solution

kk=1; % indexes through the data
for cc=1:numel(qp)
   % advance kk to where we can interpolate
   % (this loop is guaranteed to not index out of bounds because x_data(end)>qp(end),
   %    but needs to be adjusted if this is not ensured prior to the loop)
   while x_data(kk+1) < qp(cc)
      kk = kk + 1;
   end
   % perform online interpolation
   y_interp(cc) = myInterp(x_data(kk), x_data(kk+1), y_data(kk), y_data(kk+1), qp(cc));
end
```

As you can see, the logic is a lot simpler this way. The result is identical to `y_interp_correct`. The inner `while x_data...` loop serves the same purpose as your outer `while` loop, and would be the place where you read your data from wherever it's coming from.